# Qt custom widget update big overhead

Tags: qt, qtembedded, custom-widgets

We are trying to use Qt 4.8.5 for some Linux-based embedded devices in our company. I use Qt embedded without X server. I need to plot measured data and update them very often (20-30fps, but only a small portion of the widget). The system is ARM based, 400Mhz, have no GPU and no FPU. I subclassed QWidget and overridden the paintEvent(). I have WA_OpaquePaintEvent and WA_StaticContents set. For testing, my paint event is empty, and I call the update() function of the widget form a timer set to 50ms. My problem is that the empty update is eating up 30% of the CPU. The amount varies with the area of the update, so I think QT may redraw something in the background. I have read many posts but I cannot find the solution for my problem. If I comment out the update call, the CPU usage drops to ~1% (even if I generate a sine in the timer for testing the widget, which should be much more complex than an empty function call). My widget is rectangular, is not transparent and I want to handle the full drawing procedure from the paint event.

Is it possible to reduce this overhead, and handle the whole painting process by my own?

Comment: If you want to update only a small part, did you try with restricting the updated area via update(QRect) or update(QRegion)?

Comment: Yes, I tried. If I do so, the CPU usage drops in respection of the area size. But for example it is cheaper to update a 25 pixel wide region than the two 5 pixel regions separated by 15 unchanged pixels, which is not updated. For debugging, I entriely disabled my painter, and the paintEvent is only an empty function. My problem is that if I don't do anything in the paintEvent function, why it uses CPU at all? (I know it must be scheduled and called, but it should be a minimal overhead, and shoud not be proportional to updated area).

Comment: Well, the widget will also be updated if you paint nothing explicitly, as any previous content will be cleared.

Comment: Can this be somehow turned off? If I draw the content it will be cleared anyway so it is yust wasting of expensive CPU cycles. And it loads the CPU even if I draw the widget (the 2x5 vs 1x25 pixel update from my previous comment).

Comment: Another: If the clearing eats up the cpu cycles, then why is clearing a two separate 5x600 pixel columns are slower than clearing a single 25x600?

Comment: @xdever, I suggest you share some code with us; it may be that the problem you're seeing is not actually due to what you've described to us.

Comment: remember that empty while loop will also eat your CPU.

Comment: Did you tried Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground ?

Comment: Have you tried setting [Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum)?  Your success with this depends on the screen driver you are using.  It disables the double buffering which may be causing the CPU overhead you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The "empty update" is not empty - it repaints the whole window :)

Have you read the below?

*To rapidly update custom widgets with simple background colors, such as real-time plotting or graphing widgets, it is better to define a suitable background color (using setBackgroundRole() with the QPalette::Window role), set the autoFillBackground property, and only implement the necessary drawing functionality in the widget's paintEvent().*

You should also be using `QWidget::scroll()`, since internally it does scroll the backing store of the window, and that's much more efficient than repainting the entire thing if only a tiny slice is added to it.